# PrettyFaces Redirect Loop on invalid URLs

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf-2, prettyfaces

I am working on a web application based on Java and JSF2.0 and I am using Google AppEngine to host it. I am using PrettyFaces for modifying the URLs. Since I started using PrettyFaces, if someone enters an invalid URL, redirect looping occurs like the following:

```
www.example.com
```

is the website
so if you enter

```
www.example.com/invalidasdas
```

it keeps appending index.jsp to the end of the invalid URL such as :

```
www.example.com/invalidasdas/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp/index.jsp
```

I am not sure how I can fix this problem. Any suggestions to fix this would be nice. I can post my code if needed.

PrettyFaces Configuration:

```
    <pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces
                      http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-prettyfaces.xsd">

    <url-mapping id="home">
        <pattern value="/home/" />
        <view-id value="/index.jsf" />
    </url-mapping>
    <url-mapping id="blog">
        <pattern value="/blog/" />
        <view-id value="/blog.jsf" />
    </url-mapping>
    <url-mapping id="stockpicks">
        <pattern value="/stocks/" />
        <view-id value="/stockpicks.jsf" />
    </url-mapping>
    <url-mapping id="login">
        <pattern value="/login/" />
        <view-id value="/adminlogin.jsf" />
    </url-mapping>
    <url-mapping id="dashboard">
        <pattern value="/dashboard/" />
        <view-id value="/dashboard.jsf" />
    </url-mapping>
    <url-mapping id="error">
        <pattern value="/error/" />
        <view-id value="/WEB-INF/error.jsf" />
    </url-mapping>
    <url-mapping id="search">
        <pattern value="/search/#{searchBean.type}/#{searchBean.value}"></pattern>
        <view-id value="/search.jsf"/>
    </url-mapping>

</pretty-config>
```

And here's my web.xml file!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>eot</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>  
    <extension>otf</extension>  
    <mime-type>font/opentype</mime-type>  
  </mime-mapping>      
  <mime-mapping>  
    <extension>ttf</extension>  
    <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>  
  </mime-mapping>      
  <mime-mapping>  
    <extension>woff</extension>  
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>  
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>  
    <extension>svg</extension>  
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>  
  </mime-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>
     javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY
    </param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <error-page> 
    <error-code>404</error-code> 
    <location>/error/</location>
  </error-page>

  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>10080</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
      <max-age>10080</max-age>
    </cookie-config>
  </session-config>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>PrettyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrettyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>  

  <filter>
      <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>filters.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/dashboard/*</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/dashboard.jsf</url-pattern>
      <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict direct access to XHTML files</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>XHTML files</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
  </security-constraint> 

</web-app>
```

EDIT: It turns out that the issue is AppEngine and not PrettyFaces. Please stop editing posts without really looking into the problem. Someone removed the AppEngine tag and it is annoying!

Comment: Could you include your PrettyFaces configuration please?

Comment: @chkal alright done.

Comment: Do you map http errors to specific pages in your web.xml?

Comment: Could you post your web.xml? This is a very strange behavior. I'm not actually sure that PrettyFaces is causing this, based on what you've got in your config. Do you use any annotations to configure PrettyFaces, or is this it?

Comment: @Lincoln Hi Lincoln. I've added my web.xml file. Also, if you want to see this behavior happen live, you can go to http://www.aayushmittal.com . Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: Hmm. That all looks normal. Does this also happen if you run on a typical Java EE container such as WildFly, TomEE, or GlassFish? Can you reproduce with a minimal application and perhaps upload to http://ocpsoft.org/support/ forum?

Comment: @Lincoln I will try to reproduce the problem soon with a different server. I just noticed something interesting. If I run this Google AppEngine app on the localhost, it gives me a proper 404 page. But, if it is hosted on AppEngine and then run, it loops infinitely. I believe this issue might not be because of PrettyFaces afterall!

Comment: Great! I am glad that you figured out the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue that yours, but when I add "/WEB-INF" to view-id value it work ! ie:

```
    ...
    <url-mapping id="home">
            <pattern value="/home/" />
            <view-id value="/WEB-INF/index.jsf" />
    </url-mapping>
    ...
```

it works, but I am not convinced by this solution, I am trying to investigate it

Comment: Ah I see. In my case, I do not know what was happening but the worst part was that the Google AppEngine didn't let me have custom error page for error codes such as 404. So, I ended up moving to VPS with the same code and project setup, and everything works!